# Requesting additional FB permissions on an existing/approved app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've got an existing app with a few thousand users. I'd like to add extra functionality which necessitates requesting new permissions.

Will requesting the new permissions (essentially making a new review request) move my app into unpublished status? Or will it continue to function with the existing granted permissions while login review takes place for the new?

Might be a stupid question - but didn't see any documentation on it and want to ensure I'm not cutting off service for the 4-5 days that it takes them to review/approve/possibly deny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will requesting the new permissions (essentially making a new review request) move my app into unpublished status?

No. Review has nothing to do with the app’s status of being in development or live.

> Or will it continue to function with the existing granted permissions while login review takes place for the new?

Yes, all permissions your app had already been granted previously will continue to work. Even if your newly submitted permissions would not be approved for some reason, the already approved ones stay approved.
(That is, of course, unless they find out now, that you app uses them for something that is not compliant with Platform Policy.)